# Need Guidance on Docker Setup

Tags: docker

I am doing web development for few years. I usually have Xampp installed on my windows machine, and one version of mysql with me. It serves me well, but now we have some old project that need old version of mysql or PHP.

I can install older version of Xampp and use different ports and work as I do, but then I realise we have Docker, and I have powerful enough machine. So I try to experiment it and run docker of mysql and use it for development, but when I close the docker machine/host shutdown the docker clean old data and is no longer available to me.

I am reading that we can link to my host harddisk, but everyday I need to reinstall everything and then work on it seems like not a good method to do it.

Is there any way that I can keep environment safe and easily usable. I am not sure how I Can do that? I don't need much of technical details as I can find documentation on it, but I am still nto clear on flow/workflow on how to setup. I usually work on 3-4 project per day so I have to fast switch between environment and make it seemless as much as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an entire Docker-based "environment" using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), a tool which allows you to specify multiple containers, how they talk to each other, and what data within those containers is persisted.

For this specific example, you'd include a MySQL container in your `docker-compose.yml` and define a `volume` linking to `/var/lib/mysql` in the container. Create the same volume in the `volumes` section of `docker-compose.yml`, and your data will persist across `docker-compose up`/`docker-compose down` cycles, and even after deleting the built container.

This is based on Docker's [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) functionality. You don't have to store volumes on your local machine -- Docker offers other providers that let you use cloud/network-based storage instead (obviously this is slower than local disk).

For your web container, you can specify a "link" to the MySQL container, allowing you to resolve it using docker-compose's internal DNS functionality as "mysql" or something similar.

Comment: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes the network environment containers run in and how they can talk to each other.  You don't need to manually specify links in modern Docker.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, so I make a Composer YML, and it attach to my local disk and everytime I need to work on project I do docker compose on folder to start DOCKERFILE. that sounds promising, but I wonder how efficient that method is. Let me try that. Thanks.